# Why my views.py doesn't save submitted csv file in data folder in my app directory in Django project?

Tags: python, django, server, django-views, http-post

Hello I am working on a project Django.

I am trying to save a file after users submits it from webpage.

I created views and HTML..

part of the views.py, html and urls.py are provided below.

Can i get some help why my code is not saving file in data folder in my app directory?

views.py

```
class CsvPlot(View):
    def save_uploaded_file(self, request, file):
        if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES[file]:
            uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
            # attribute = request.Post.get("attribute")
            # print(attribute)
            # check if the file ends with csv
            if uploaded_file.name.endswith('.csv'):
                save_file = FileSystemStorage()
                name = save_file.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
                print(name)
                # Let's save the file in the data folder
                current_dir = settings.BASE_DIR / 'ml_in_geotech'
                file_directory = os.path.join(current_dir, 'data')
                if not os.path.exists(file_directory):
                    os.makedirs(file_directory)
                self.file_path = os.path.join(file_directory, name)
                self.readfile(request, self.file_path)
                request.session['file_path'] = self.file_path
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid file type. Only CSV files are allowed.')
```

My HTML

```
<div class="upload_file">
    <h2>Train Your Data</h2>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="file" name="document" id="document" required="required">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>   
    
    {% block messages %}
        {% if messages %}
            <div class="container" style="color: firebrick; margin-top: 20px" >
            {% for message in messages %}
                {{ message }}
            {% endfor %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endblock %}

  </div>
```

My urls.py

```
[
  path('csv-plot/', views.CsvPlot.as_view(), name='csv_plot'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

see the typical structure difference of function based views and classe based views in django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/

function based view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def my_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse("result")
```

class based view:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import View


class MyView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        # <view logic>
        return HttpResponse("result")
```

in your case should be something like:

```
class CsvPlot(View):
    def post(self, request, file):
        if request.FILES[file]:
            uploaded_file = request.FILES['document']
        ...
```

and make sure that for every if/else clause a valid Http response is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had another typo on my HTML. after fixing that I am able to save the file.